TON blockchain: How to check a transaction is success or not?
I use tonweb lirary to send a transaction. But the response I receive is some thing like { '@type': 'ok', '@extra': '1723716788.6499352:4:0.3484654105500832' }. This is a quite useless information, I don't know if my transaction is success or failed.
I tried to call to getTransaction() method to get my latest transaction, but I dont see the information about my transaction is success or not in there.

Solution: Using api of tonapi.io docs here to trace all exit code in transaction and children message
Pros: Can trace all messages in transaction just from transaction hash or message hash. You can get message hash before you send transaction to blockchain.
Cons: Has api rate limit (1 req/s for free user)
import { HttpClient, Api, Trace } from 'tonapi-sdk-js';

const API_KEY = "API_KEY";
// Configure the HTTP client with your host and token
const httpClient = new HttpClient({
    baseUrl: 'https://testnet.tonapi.io',
    baseApiParams: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
});

// Initialize the API client
const client = new Api(httpClient);

(async () => {
    const trace = await client.traces.getTrace("messsage hash")
    // console.log(trace)
    console.log(isTraceSuccess(trace))
})()

function isTraceSuccess(trace: Trace): { isSuccess: boolean, errorTransaction: any } {
    if (!trace.transaction.success) {
        // console.log(trace.transaction)
        return { isSuccess: false, errorTransaction: trace.transaction };
    }
    if (trace.children) {
        for (let i = 0; i < trace.children?.length; i++) {
            const res = isTraceSuccess(trace.children[i]);
            if (!res.isSuccess) {
                return { isSuccess: false, errorTransaction: res.errorTransaction };
            }
        }
    }

    return { isSuccess: true, errorTransaction: undefined };
}

ps: tonapi has api endpoint to emulate transaction before actually send to blockchain
